# Why does the UnbloundLocalError occur when calling the Deposit() and Withdraw() methods?

Tags: python

Just wondering why when running this code and calling wither Deposit() or Withdraw() always returns the same error:

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'balance' referenced before assignment

I have tried initializing the Account class and taking balance as one of the args, the same error occurs.

```
class Customer:

    AccountName = ""

    accounts = []

    def __init__(self, name, pin):
        self.name = name
        self.pin = pin
        
    def GetNewAccountInfo():
        name = str(input("Enter Account Name: "))

        pin = str(input("Enter Account Pin: "))

        AccountName = name + pin
        Customer.CreateNewAccount(AccountName)

    def CreateNewAccount(AccountName):
        Customer.accounts += AccountName
        Account.MainWindow()

class Account:

    balance = 0

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def Withdraw():
        amount = int(input("Enter the amount you wish to withdraw:"))
        if amount <= 0:
            print("You cannot withdraw a negative or zero amount.")
            Account.Withdraw()
        else:
            balance -= amount
            print(balance)
            Account.MainWindow()


    def Deposit():
        amount = int(input("Enter the amount you wish to depsoit: "))
        if amount <= 0:
            print("You cannot deposit a negative or zero amount.")
            Account.Depsoit()
        else:
            balance += amount
            print(balance)
            Account.MainWindow()

    def CheckBalance():
        print(balance)

    def MainWindow():
        selection = int(input(" 1. Withdraw \n 2. Deposit \n 3. CheckBalance \n 4. Main Menu \n "))
        if selection == 1:
            Account.Withdraw()
        elif selection == 2:
           Account.Deposit()
        elif selection == 3:
            Account.CheckBalance()
        elif selection == 4:
            Account.MainWindow()
        else:
            print("Enter a valid int selection: ")
            Account.MainWindow()

Customer.GetNewAccountInfo()
```

Comment: You are confusing the class, and instances of the class.  I will post an answer with the proper organization.

Comment: Post the full traceback message so we can see the failing line.

Comment: `balance` is **not** a local variable inside the `Withdraw()` and `Deposit()` functions.  It is a **class attribute** and therefore you must use the class name when referring to it: `Account.balance`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more proper way to organize this.  Notice here that we create OBJECTS from the class and work with the objects.  We don't work with the classes directly.  Note that the Customer class creates and tracks a set of Account objects.  Notice that the main menu is a mainline function, not a part of the class.  This works.

```
class Customer:

    accounts = []

    def __init__(self, name=None, pin=None):
        self.name = name
        self.pin = pin
        
    def GetNewAccountInfo(self):
        self.name = input("Enter Account Name: ")
        self.pin = input("Enter Account Pin: ")
        AccountName = self.name + self.pin
        self.CreateNewAccount(AccountName)

    def CreateNewAccount(self, AccountName):
        self.accounts.append( Account(AccountName) )

class Account:

    name = "None"
    balance = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def Withdraw(self):
        while True:
            amount = int(input("Enter the amount you wish to withdraw:"))
            if amount <= 0:
                print("You cannot withdraw a negative or zero amount.")
            else:
                self.balance -= amount
                print(self.balance)
                break

    def Deposit(self):
        while True:
            amount = int(input("Enter the amount you wish to depsoit: "))
            if amount <= 0:
                print("You cannot deposit a negative or zero amount.")
            else:
                self.balance += amount
                print(self.balance)
                break

    def CheckBalance(self):
        print(self.balance)

def MainMenu(customer):
    account = customer.accounts[0]
    selection = int(input(" 1. Withdraw \n 2. Deposit \n 3. CheckBalance \n 4. Exit \n"))
    if selection == 1:
        account.Withdraw()
    elif selection == 2:
        account.Deposit()
    elif selection == 3:
        account.CheckBalance()
    else:
        return 0
    return 1

customer = Customer()
customer.GetNewAccountInfo()
while MainMenu(customer):
    pass
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This explanation cleared a lot of things up for me. Also, I like the way you started the script itself
```
customer = Customer()
customer.GetNewAccountInfo()
while MainMenu(customer)
     pass
```

I would have never thought to do something like this!